# How to render response for a particular route request directly from a listener in symfony?

Tags: symfony

I have a route for which I want to return the response template directly from my listener. But that particular request is giving me 404 response code as I haven't made a controller for this route. How to solve this issue if I don't want to make any controller for this route. [Here's the sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLCKe.png)

Comment: Which event does your listener react to? Can you show the code and configuration?

Comment: Please provide some example code to illustrate the problem you're facing and to help allow others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do, is render a template, you can also use [FrameworkBundle's TemplateController](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#rendering-a-template-directly-from-a-route):

```sh
#config/routes.yaml
index:
    path: /
    methods: ['GET']
    controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\TemplateController
    defaults:
        template: 'index.html.twig'
```

If you do not want to use a controller or need more than just rendering, you have to make sure that your event listener is called before Symfony attempts to match your path, e.g. `/` to a controller. [The Symfony docs on the HttpKernel-component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-workflow-of-a-request) explain the request cycle and the events in more detail.

You want to listen to the `kernel.request`-event. To make sure that your listener runs before the RouterListener. You will probably have to change the listeners priority for this. You can check whether the listener is found and which order it runs in by running a debug command. In my example the RouterListener is #5 in the list and yours should be before that:

```sh
bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.request

Registered Listeners for "kernel.request" Event
===============================================

 ------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
  Order   Callable                                                                                Priority
 ------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
  #1      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure()           2048
  #2      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest()   256
  #3      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest()           128
  #4      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::setDefaultLocale()           100
  #5      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest()            32
  #6      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest()            16
 ------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
```

In your event listener you have to be careful to not return the Response, like you would do with a Controller, but instead set the Response on the event, e.g. like this:

```php
public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    if ($request->isMasterRequest() === false) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if the request matches your criteria, e.g. by checking the path
    // otherwise "return;" 

    $response = new Response($this->twig->render('my_template.html.twig'));

    $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: Where does `$this->twig` come from?

Comment: You can inject it in the constructor. It should be type hinted to the twig runtime class